# WPF datagrid - value of the edited cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am working on [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) datagrid control. Binding the data from code behind using a dataset/XML. I want to edit the cell of the grid and capture the new value which the user has entered. Is there a code sample to show how to do that?

What event should I use and which property of datagrid (if any) should I use, selecteditem or selectedcell?

(I am kind of new to WPF datagrid control, so I apologize if this is kind of kiddish...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CellEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [RowEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending). You can access the respective row and its [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.item) from the event arguments.